# How to copy all files via FTP in rsync

Tags: linux, ftp, rsync

I have online account with some Host which give me FTP account with username and password .

i have another with copany which gave me FTP and rsync .

Now i want to transfer all my files from old FTP to NEW FTP with rync.

Now is it possible to do it via rsync only because i don't want to first copy on computer and then upload again

Comment: Do you have shells on either or both hosts?

Comment: i have only ftp on one host and FTP, SFTP, rsync, SCP, SSH  on other host

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lets call the machine with only FTP `src`.

Lets call the machine with FTP and SSH `dst`.

```
ssh dst
cd destination-direction
wget --mirror --ftp-user=username --ftp-password=password\
     --no-host-directories ftp://src/pathname/
```

Note that running `wget` with `--ftp-password` on the command line will give away the password to anyone else on the system. (As well as transferring it over the wire in the clear, but you knew that.)

If you don't have access to `wget`, then they might have `ncftp` or `lftp` or `ftp` installed. I just happen to know `wget` the best. :)

**Edit** To use `ftp`, you'll need to do something more like:

```
ftp src
user username
pass password
bin
cd /pathname
ls
```

At this point, note all the directories on the remote system. Create each one with `!mkdir`. Then change into the directory both locally and remotely:

```
lcd <dirname>
cd <dirname>
ls
```

Repeat for all the directories. Use `mget *` to get all the files.

If this looks awful, it is because it is. FTP wasn't designed for this, and if your new host doesn't have better tools (be sure to look for `ncftp` and `lftp` and maybe something like `ftpmirror`), then either compile better tools yourself or get good at writing scripts around the bad tools. :)

Or if you could get a shell on `src`, that'd help immensely too. FTP is just not intended for transferring thousands of files.

Anyway, this avoids bouncing through your local system, which ought to help throughput significantly.

Comment: i don't have wget but has ftp , how to change ur command with ftp

Comment: i have another linux host on internet , i think i need first wget all files there and then from there use rsync to destination

Comment: Oh yes, that sounds much better. :) You could also `tar` the files on the intermediate system, assuming you've got the drive space, and just transfer a _single_ file between the middle-man host. That'd beat `rsync` by a lot. :)

Comment: in your Wget command above , where to enter the ftp host name

Comment: wget from nfs share also downloads files. thanks :-)

Answer (score 4):

There's always the trusty FUSE filesystems, [CurlFtpFS](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) and [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html). Mount each server with the appropriate filesystem and copy across using standard utilities. Probably not the fastest way to do it, but quite possibly the least labor-intensive.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a simple solution to sync a remote folder to a local folder via FTP while only replacing new files. I got stuck with a little **`wget`** script based on [**sarnold**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377270)'s [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5987082/2656118) that I thought might be helpful to others, too, so here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash    
HOST="1.2.3.4"
USER="username"
PASS="password"
LDIR="/path/to/local/dir"    # can be empty
RDIR="/path/to/remote/dir"   # can be empty

cd $LDIR && \                # only start if the cd was successful
wget \
  --continue \               # resume on files that have already been partially transmitted
  --mirror \                 # --recursive --level=inf --timestamping --no-remove-listing
  --no-host-directories \    # don't create 'ftp://src/' folder structure for synced files
  --ftp-user=$USER \
  --ftp-password=$PASS \
    ftp://$HOST/$RDIR
```